# Azure to on premise

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I have a simple Xamarin Forms application that uses an SQL database and backend code for device synchronization hosted on MS Azure. Everything works fine but the company I work for have asked if the Azure backend could be moved to an on premise server. Is this possible?

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO!  The simple answer is yes, maybe.  Without details of your app and environment, however, an answer is only a guess.  You will need to research the steps required for your given environment and then you can come back here to ask about any specific problems you run into.

Comment: squillman, thanks for the reply. I found this example but I thought I could just install the required software on the on premise server without requiring a VM. http://techgenix.com/moving-azure-vm-on-premise/

Comment: What azure service(s) are you using when you say *an SQL database and backend code for device synchronization hosted on MS Azure.*?

Comment: Peter, I created an App Service (WebApp + SQL). Basically if you created the Quick Start Todo sample my services would use the same resources. Thanks Paul.